# Reading app that shows footnotes on the bottom of the page in fb2 documents

Tags: 8.1, apps

I am used to read footnotes on the same page with a reference, so I see the context and don't have to tap a small number to read a footnote. Is there an app that shows footnotes on the bottom of the page in fb2 documents?

Comment: Can you send a link to an fb2 that has footnotes and I'll try it in my ebook reader.

Comment: @Eric See [Les Miserables](http://fictionbook-lib.org/showbook.php?id=1). The first footnote is for Tso-maraude in book second chapter I.